# How to get a point on an ellipse's outline given an angle?

Tags: geometry, ellipse

So, I have ellipses given - they are defined by their midpoint, an horizontal radius(rh) and an vertical radius(rv). I'm drawing them using sin/cos and the result looks fairly good to me(just making sure this isn't an error source).

Now say I have an angle(or a direction vector) given and I want to have the point on the ellipse's outline with that angle/direction. My intuitive approach was to simply use the direction vector, normalise it and multiply its x-component with rh, its y-component with rv. Now both my written program AND all the calculations I did on a paper give me not the point I want but another one, though it's still on the ellipse's outline. However, this method works just fine if the direction is one of (1,0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (so it works for 0°, 90°, 180°, 270°).

Although there is a farily big amount of data about ellipses themselves on the internet, I couldn't find any information about my particular problem - and I couldn't come up with any better solution than the above one.

So, any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking then I think that what you need is [**polar form of an ellipse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) where the angle is measured from the ellipse centre. Using this form of the ellipse, you will be able to evaulate your elliptic radius value for a given choice of theta and then plot your point.

If you take a look at this gif image you will see why using the **parametric** angle give you the correct result **only** at theta = 90, 180, 270 and 360 degrees http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Parametric_ellipse.gif . Use the polar form for an ellipse and you should get the points that you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - the parametric angle is *not* the same as the angle between the desired point and the X axis.  However, their tangents are proportional (with a factor of `rh/rv`) so you can use this approach:

- Get the tangent of the desired angle
- Multiply this tangent by `rh/rv`
- Use [trigonometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Related_identities) to compute the sine and cosine from the tangent
- Scale/position the point according to the parameters (midpoint, rh, rv)

In Python:

```
from math import copysign, cos, sin, sqrt

class Ellipse:

        def __init__(self, mx, my, rh, rv):
                self.mx = mx
                self.my = my
                self.rh = rh
                self.rv = rv

        def pointFromAngle(self, a):
                c = cos(a)
                s = sin(a)
                ta = s / c  ## tan(a)
                tt = ta * self.rh / self.rv  ## tan(t)
                d = 1. / sqrt(1. + tt * tt)
                x = self.mx + copysign(self.rh * d, c)
                y = self.my + copysign(self.rv * tt * d, s)
                return x, y
```